# Jest: how to get the report of code overage/ components without tests within a specific folder (or maybe project if that is feasible)?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I am writing unit tests for my React JS components in a specific folder using Jest testing framework. All my components are within, let's say, "src/components" folder. I can get the coverage of each test adding "--coverage" flag when I run the command as follow.

```
jest --watchAll --coverage
```

It's going to generate the report in the coverage folder and I can view the code coverage of each tests as follow.
[image]

That is going to display the code coverage of each component that is included in the tests. But how can I see the list of components that are not yet covered in the tests (maybe the list of components that are not yet covered in the tests within a specific folder). Is it possible to get the stats for that in percentage too? How can I do that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Add the collectCoverageFrom paths to your extra folders, using the glob pattern.  For instance, I have:

```
collectCoverage: true,
collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/**/*.ts',
    '!<rootDir>/**/*.interface.ts',
    '!<rootDir>/**/*.mock.ts',
    '!<rootDir>/**/*.module.ts',
    '!<rootDir>/**/__mock__/*',
    '!<rootDir>/src/main.ts'
],
```